# Calculate Running total in a new column based Adding or Subtracting condition using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, partitioning, cumulative-sum

I am trying to calculate running total based on the value plus/minus in another column by Account and Date.

Example

```
Data 
ID     Account  Date         Operation         Qty              Running_Total 
1       A       01/01/2018       plus           10              10
2       A       01/02/2018       plus           20              30 
3       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
4       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
5       A       01/04/2018       plus           30              50
6       B       01/01/2018       plus           15              15
```

the total

```
Code: 
select ID, Date, Operation, Total, 
              case when Operation = 'Use Table B' then TableB.RunningTotalQty 
              else
              SUM( case when Operation = 'plus' then  Qty 
                   else case when Operation = 'minus' then -Qty end) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Date)  end
            From TableA A left Join TableB B 
on A.ID = B.ID ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

The `case` goes inside the `sum()`:

```
select ID, Date, Operation, Total, 
       sum(case when Operation = 'plus' then qty else - qty end) over
           (partition by Account order by Date) as Running_Total
From TableA  ;
```

This assumes only two operations.  If you have more:

```
select ID, Date, Operation, Total, 
       sum(case when Operation = 'plus' then qty
                then Operation = 'minus' then - qty
                else 0
           end) over
           (partition by Account order by Date) as Running_Total
From TableA  ;
```

Comment: There is another case, where Operation is "Use Table B" and Value is a number coming from another source Table B which reset the running total. How to edit for that scenario?

Comment: Can you please see an additional request

Comment: @rachel . . . Changing the question after it has been answer is rude.  It can invalidate answers and thereby draw downvotes.  I would suggest that you revert this question (because no one has answered the revised part) and ask another question.

Comment: I am really sorry about that. I was not sure how to ask follow-up question. Not trying to be rude or anything at all. I am still learning how to use this platform. I will revert back to original question and post another one for follow-up edits. Really sincere apologies.